# Docker : initial installation script fails (ubuntu 13.04 , kernel 3.8+)

Tags: linux, shell, installation, docker

I created this script according to docker.io installation instructions for Ubuntu 13.04 with 3.8+ kernel, but script is interrupted as lxc-docker installation fihishes.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeychecking=no -t -t -i $CERT $USER@$SERVER <<'ENDSSH'

sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install software-properties-common
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive add-apt-repository -y ppa:dotcloud/lxc-docker
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install lxc-docker

echo "some other actions here..."

exit #SSH session

ENDSSH
exit
```

Last line of installation process is :

```
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

and then it will stay on command line, but that is not good. I want to install few other things and exit properly by exit command from remote machine.

Where is problem here ?

I do not want to use some more complex remote provisioning tools like puppet/chef/salt , would be great to have already prepared 100% reliable docker installation scripts for various OS.

Thank you

Comment: Is it failing or just taking to long to process the triggers?

Comment: It jumps on command line and then nothing happens (as script has stopped in the middle).

Comment: If you run those same commands manually on the server what does it do? If it also stops then it is something with the server.

Comment: yes it also stops there

Comment: OK, so if it stops there when you manually do the install then it is something with the server. Is this a local server, managed server, cloud server, etc? Can you install anything else via apt-get?

Comment: It's vanilla Ubuntu instance in AWS.